# jQuery radio button value is not changed on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-forms, radio-button, django-admin

I searched the net and tried all solutions for similar questions from SO, but just can't get this one working.

I am working in Django admin, and I have `RadioSelect` widget for the field `is_valid`, with two radio buttons in the form:

```
 <div class="form-row field-is_valid">       
    <div>           
        <label for="id_is_valid_0">Is it valid?</label>
                        
        <ul id="id_is_valid" class="inline">
            <li><label for="id_is_valid_0"><input type="radio" name="is_valid" value="True" id="id_is_valid_0" checked>
                    Yes
                </label>
            </li>
            <li><label for="id_is_valid_1"><input type="radio" name="is_valid" value="False" id="id_is_valid_1">
                    No
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>      
</div>

<div class="form-row field-not_valid_reason">
    <div>
        <label for="id_not_valid_reason">Reason:</label>
        <select name="not_valid_reason" id="id_not_valid_reason">
          <option value="" selected>Choose</option>
          <option value="Expired">Expired</option>
          <option value="Not adopted">Not adopted</option>
          <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
        </select>             
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide a class `.field-not_valid_reason` when 'Yes' (`True`) is checked (which is default for `is_valid` field) and show it when I click 'No'. This I accomplished.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
 (function($) {
    $(function() {
        var isValid = $('input[type=radio][name=is_valid]'),
            notValidReason = $('.field-not_valid_reason'),


            function toggleFields(value) {
                if (value === 'True') {
                    notValidReason.hide(250);
                } else {
                    notValidReason.show(250);
                }
            }

        // show/hide on load based on previous value of isValid
        toggleFields(isValid.val());

        // show/hide on change
        isValid.change(function() {
            toggleFields($(this).val());
            alert(isValid.val());
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

But, for some reason, after the object is saved in the database with the `is_valid` field False, when I am on the change page of that object, the class `.field-not_valid_reason` is hidden, albeit active radio button is set to "No" (`False`).
Can you help, please?

Comment: Hi , where is `.field-not_valid_reason` in your html code ?

Comment: And .. `alert(isValid.val());` will show always `true` .Instead use `alert($(this).val());` that will give correct value .. Also on load just hide the `.field-not_valid_reason` by default ..

Comment: @Swati thanks for `alert($(this).val());`. I also updated html code with the `.field-not_valid_reason`. This class is by default hidden in the new form, since the default for `is_valid` is `True`. However, if I open the form which was saved with `is_valid` is `False`, `.field-not_valid_reason` is again hidden and should be shown.

Comment: How you save value for `is_valid` ? and what do you mean by `if I open the form which..`

Comment: I am working in Django admin so the value of `is_valid` is saved in database on save of the object that is presented by the form (I hope I explained it properly). When I say `if I open the form which..`, I mean that I am opening the change page of the object in the admin.

Comment: That means radio is showing correct value when page load.. but the div is hidden...so can pass `checked` radio button value to your `toggleFields` function ..when page gets load. i.e :`$("input[name='is_valid']:checked"). val();`

Comment: @Swati thank you very much, this worked. I was passing `checked` value to `isValid` variable like `var isValid = $('input[type=radio][name=is_valid]:checked')`, but it wasn't working...obviously I still don't get js :)

Comment: @Swati Please turn your comments into an answer so that vladobl can select it as the correct answer and close out this question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current **jquery** code you where using `alert(isValid.val());` to see which option is selected but this will give you first value only so to get current value which user has selected use `$(this).val()`.

Then , onload you where getting right value for `radio` but the div was still hidden because you are again passing `toggleFields(isValid.val());` which will give you first value only .So , to overcome this pass `radio` value which is `checked` i.e : `$("input[name='is_valid']:checked").val()` .